# how can to turn a python that use tkinter into dmg file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2app

so I've been looking on the internet for a solution but none has worked I am trying to turn this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import choice, randint, shuffle
import pyperclip
import json

# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #

#Password Generator Project
def generate_password():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

    password_letters = [choice(letters) for _ in range(randint(8, 10))]
    password_symbols = [choice(symbols) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]
    password_numbers = [choice(numbers) for _ in range(randint(2, 4))]

    password_list = password_letters + password_symbols + password_numbers
    shuffle(password_list)

password = "".join(password_list)
password_entry.insert(0, password)
pyperclip.copy(password)

# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #
def save():

    website = website_entry.get()
    email = email_entry.get()
    password = password_entry.get()
    new_data = {
        website: {
            "email": email,
            "password": password,
    }
}

if len(website) == 0 or len(password) == 0:
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Oops", message="Please make sure you haven't left any fields empty.")
else:
    try:
        with open("data.json", "r") as data_file:
            #Reading old data
            data = json.load(data_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
            json.dump(new_data, data_file, indent=4)
    else:
        #Updating old data with new data
        data.update(new_data)

        with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
            #Saving updated data
            json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
    finally:
        website_entry.delete(0, END)
        password_entry.delete(0, END)


# ---------------------------- FIND PASSWORD ------------------------------- #
def find_password():
    website = website_entry.get()
    try:
        with open("data.json") as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="No Data File Found.")
    else:
        if website in data:
            email = data[website]["email"]
            password = data[website]["password"]
            messagebox.showinfo(title=website, message=f"Email: {email}\nPassword: {password}")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message=f"No details for {website} exists.")


# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(height=200, width=200)
logo_img = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=logo_img)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Labels
website_label = Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
email_label = Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
password_label = Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

#Entries
website_entry = Entry(width=21)
website_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
website_entry.focus()
email_entry = Entry(width=35)
email_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)
email_entry.insert(0, "")
password_entry = Entry(width=21)
password_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)

# Buttons
search_button = Button(text="Search", width=13, command=find_password)
search_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
generate_password_button = Button(text="Generate Password", command=generate_password)
generate_password_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
add_button = Button(text="Add", width=36, command=save)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

To have it like an app on my Mac, the code works fine and all when I run it, I want it to launch like an app if it's possible

I tried `pyinstaller` and `py2app` but none seemed to work, I follow a tutorial said to type in the terminal :

```bash
pyinstaller main.py
```

Comment: What didn't work? What went wrong? Please check [ask] and [MRE] for tips on what sorts of info to provide about the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to create `setup file` in directory where is your app. And also import `py2app`. For more info on how to properly create setup file try [docs](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html).

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app_mame.py']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True
}

setup(
    app=APP, 
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

After creating setup file you need to run this command in terminal > `python3 setup.py py2app`.
After a while you should see `dist` directory where your **.dmg** file will be located.

Comment: ok so i just tried what you said and i got a few : modules not found (unconditional import ) and modules not found (conditional imports) at the end of the terminal  , i can also see the new dist file which contain the dmg file but it crashes with the error "quit unexpectedly."

Comment: @Adam for those imports try this `python3 setup.py py2app -A`. Also run this command in your terminal to debug your app, it will show you exact errors > `dist/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName`

Comment: sorry for late reply , thank you it worked , i also just needed to edit a few stuff in the setup to include some data